# .htaccess to nginx rewite

Tags: linux, nginx

please help me with changing this .htaccess to rginx rewite

```
RewriteRule   ^show.php/(.*)$ show2.php?img=$1 [L]
RewriteRule   ^out.php/([a-z]{1})(.*)$ out2.php?$1=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule   ^view.php/(.*)$ view2.php?img=$1 [L]
RewriteRule   ^images.php/([a-z]{1})(.*)$ images2.php?$1=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule   ^gallery/([0-9]+)-([^/]*)/(.*)$ gallery.php?gal=$1&img=$3 [L]
RewriteRule   ^view/([0-9]+)-([^/]*)/(.*)$ gallery_body.php?gal=$1&img=$3 [L]
```

Comment: A) How does this belong here? B) Use code tags please C) Search on stackoverflow before asking

Comment: I think this is perfectly valid here; it's about Nginx configuration. Yes, you can argue, it's app related, but, as an SA, I get these requests from my developers all the time

Answer (score 2):

I've done these off the top of my head, and, I'm not able to test them:

*You need to include the / with Nginx.*

**Apache**

`RewriteRule   ^show.php/(.*)$ show2.php?img=$1 [L]`

**Nginx**

`Rewrite ^/show.php(.*)$ /show2.php?img=$1 last;`

*Nginx, query-string-append is implicit, so no special syntax.*

**Apache**

`RewriteRule   ^out.php/([a-z]{1})(.*)$ out2.php?$1=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

**Nginx**

`Rewrite ^/out.php/([a-z]{1})(.*)$ /out2.php?$1=$2 last;`

The rest of your rules seem variations of above.

Andrew